# Redirect web request

Tags: windows, http

I use a third-party application that requests a config file from their Internet site. That file is out of date, but I can create my own file with the updated information.

How can I redirect any requests coming from my computer for a specific URL to a different file? For example, if any application requests `http://www.theirsite.com/path/to/file.html`, cause it instead to receive `http://www.example.com/blah.html` or `C:\My Documents\blah.html`?

Comment: On what web server - IIS / Apache / ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not change your hosts file to point lookups to their website to a web server that you control ? Then add your own config file. You *may* have to redirect other requests to their server though, if the app uses the website for other resources.